# Rolling your own crypto

Tags: security, encryption

I know this is usually frowned upon, but supposing you were to roll your own encryption cipher (completely on your own or with a small group of friends, with no peer review possible), what could you do to make your custom algorithm as safe as possible (or rather, to keep the danger of using it to a minimum)? Similarly, what would you do for something like a hash function to make the probability of it having some trivial collision or preimage attack as low as possible?

I understand that there would be no way to approach the security of algorithms like AES, and I have no plans to use custom algorithms for anything important, but I thought it would be informative to think of what some best practices would be for rolling your own cryptosystem if you were to do so.

Comment: I'm no cryptographer, but my intuition tells me that a good way might be to write tests. Find as many "crypto hacks" as you can that are well known, and write tests to make sure your algorithm isn't vulnerable to them. Besides that, I think there isn't any way to know how secure it is (other than mathematical figures like how long it will take to guess something) until someone figures out how to break it. But again take what I'm saying with a grain of salt as I'm no cryptographer.

Comment: To misquote Ben Franklin, "Three may keep custom crypto secure if two of them are dead" and the third never uses it in production.  Maybe ask crypto questions at [security.se](https://security.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: This seems less of a specific programming problem and more a speculative question that might be better answered on [security.se].

Comment: Stackoverflow is for [programming questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Questions about **cryptography** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Crypto](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: imho it would help if you would understand how existing crypto schemas work (feistel network, s-boxes, sponge,.. ) and attacks against them (direct or side channel).  I like articles of Bruce Schneier, you may start with them at least to have feeling how deep waters you are entering